# Connecting mysql on 3306 and 3007

Tags: mysql

I am able to connect to the db instance using 3306 and 3307

mysql -hlocalhost -P 3306  -u root -proot test

mysql -hlocalhost -P 3307  -u root -proot test
This is also working.

But it is actually running only on 3307, tomcat is able to connect to db only on 3307.
What does this mean? Is it an expected output?

Comment: Are you by any chance using a Mac? Check this out: http://superuser.com/questions/972276/mysql-binds-to-port-3307-not-port-3306

Comment: `grep port /etc/[mysql/]my.cnf`, `ps aux | grep mysqld`, `nc -z localhost 3306` what are the results?

Comment: @CherryDT : Thanks. Yes.I am using mac. Somehow, it;s not picking config from my.cnf. So I changed the default port in LaunchDaemons/com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist. It's now connecting to 3306. But I am still confused, why it's not throwing an error when I was connecting on wrong port.

Answer (score 0):

Normally mysql listens only to one port (default is 3306, some installations put 3007 into the startup script for whatever reasons).

If you do not have more than one instance running this should not happen.

Comment: It's connecting on 3307, but running the commands I stated in my question,on of them should be throwing an error.